# What's with Tomorrow's Joe and the constant amount of hatching?

Tags: tomorrows-joe

Hatching is rarely used in hand-drawn animation as a whole, but in Western animation in the Americas and Western Europe, it's often done to look like an old illustration.

But when I saw the first two pilots of *Tomorrow's Joe*, it has constant use of hatching, whether regular hatching, rough hatching or crosshatching, it's almost all over the place.

What's with the pilots of the anime having constant hatching?

Comment: You mean the effect like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kICYKlQjcEU&t=517s ?